# Runtime difference Python and R when counting elements in text files

Tags: python, r, time

I'm trying to read lines from a text file, count the number of elements per line and then identify the line with the highest number of elements.

Python solution:

```
line_lengths_blogs = []
import time
t1 = time.time()
f_blogs = open("./working/en_US.blogs.capped.txt", "r")
d_blogs = f_blogs.readlines()
f_blogs.close()

for line in d_blogs:
    line_lengths_blogs.append(len(line))
print max(line_lengths_blogs)
```

Output:

```
3839
Operating time: 0.0128719806671
```

R solution:

```
t1 <- proc.time()

line_lengths_blogs <- data.frame()
loaded_file_blogs  <- file("./working/en_US.blogs.capped.txt", open="r")
d_blogs            <- readLines(loaded_file_blogs)
close(loaded_file_blogs)

for(i in 1:length(d_blogs))
{
    line_lengths_blogs <- rbind(line_lengths_blogs, nchar(d_blogs[i]))
}

print(max(line_lengths_blogs))

t2 <- proc.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

Output:

```
[1] 3831
       User      System verstrichen 
      6.015       0.027       6.042
```

For the moment, I don't care that the elements identified are actually different... But why is R around 470 times slower?

What am I doing so terribly wrong in my R code? Or am I an accidental genius at Python programming?

Working on Mac OS X 10.6.8. [The exact same data set can be obtaine here.](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/dsscapstone/dataset/Coursera-SwiftKey.zip) Only the first 10'000 lines of the data in `final/en_US/en_US.blogs.txt` of the linked file are used for the test. I hope the problem is thus exactly reproducible.

Comment: You are growing a data frame by rbind in a loop, which is very inefficient, as r has to copy it each time.

Comment: your *small*, reproducible example is over half a gig. is that some kind of record @stackoverflow

Comment: everything after `close` in the r code you can replace with `max(nchar(d_blogs))`

Comment: @rawr so this operates on every element of the file
@jeremycg How do I correctly append to a data frame then? What's the `append` equivalent in R?

Comment: Just `nchar(d_blogs)` will give you a vector in which each element represents the number of chars of the relative line. You don't need to build a `data.frame`.

Comment: well in this example you could replace the loop with `line_lengths_blogs <- do.call('rbind', as.list(d_blogs)); max(nchar(line_lengths_blogs))`.